# Can I help a user post to Facebook (& know if they did) without the hassle of app permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. I want to suggest that users on my site share a link on their Facebook wall.
2. If a user does share a link, I want to know (so I can offer them a different experience on my site from that point on).

The thing is, I don't want to make my users approve an app to get this done. It's too much friction for my use case.

So, when users on my site click my "share on Facebook" link, I want them to see this:

[image]

Not this:

[image]

Is what I have in mind possible? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> [from comments] The docs for 'Feed Dialog' suggests that that feature "prompts the user to publish an individual story to a profile's feed. This does not require any extended permissions." I'm just not clear on whether that functionality is only available within an app a user has already granted permissions to...

The Feed dialog needs an app id – either to initialize the JS SDK, or to be passed as GET parameter when invoking the dialog by URL.

But the user does *not* have to give any special permissions to the app, or even connect to it at all.

(The need to tie it to an app id is presumable to have an app and/or a developer account to block if the Feed dialog was to be used for massive spam. But since the dialog does not work without user involvement, that risk is very low.)

Comment: Thanks. Can my FB app then know when the user has shared a post this way? I'd like to be able to reward them on my site.

Comment: Yes, have a look at the docs again, section “Return Data” at the bottom of the page. But please be aware, that awarding users for making posts is not allowed by FB Platform Policies (see IV. Application Integration Points, Point 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this using Facebook's [Web Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins).

You can read the documentation in the link for more information, but I think the functionality you're looking for is available through the Like & Share plugin (which you can find [at this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)). It adds 'like' and 'share' buttons which you set up with a URL and a Javascript callback. Once the user likes or shares your page, your Javascript callback will fire.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible as per facebook policy.Without having acceptance information from user they will not allow any post in user profile.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not trying to post to a user's wall on their behalf. I just want to know if the user posted my link or not. The docs for 'Feed Dialog' suggest that that feature "prompts the user to publish an individual story to a profile's feed. This does not require any extended permissions."